# JavaScript Binding Objects

Tags: javascript

How could I do this?

**Class**

```
var Factory = (function() {

  var Class = function() {

    this.name = 'John';

    this.methods = {
      get: function(callback) {
        callback();
      }
    };

  };

  return {
    createClass: function() {
      return new Class();
    }
  };

}());
```

**Usage**

```
var MyClass = Factory.createClass();

MyClass.methods.get(function() {
   this.name // => returns undenfined
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Actually, whats the meaning of your question here? And Post your exact Problem.

Comment: Oops, ‘How could I do this?’...

Answer (score 2):

You need to save a reference to `this` in the outer `Class` function and call `call`:

```
var instance = this;

this.methods = {
  get: function(callback) {
    callback.call(instance);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Is this the only one solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Class = function() {
    // Save a reference to this that can be used in local closures.
    var me = this;

    this.name = 'John';

    this.methods = {
        get: function(callback) {
            // Use 'call()', passing the reference to the 'Class' object
            callback.call(me);
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@SLaks - The declaration of scope as a Global variable is bad practice.
@Ferdinand Beyer - have you tested if it functions?

The better way will be the scope binding. The Prototype javascript framework produced a nice concept and we can easily implement it like

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
  var _function = this;

  return function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
}
```

and then yoou code should have only a single change and it will maintin the scope of your class.

```
var Factory = (function() {

  var Class = function() {

    this.name = 'John';
    var me = this;
    this.methods = {
      get: function(callback) {

        callback();
      }
    };

  };

  return {
    createClass: function() {
      return new Class();
    }
  };

}());

var MyClass = Factory.createClass();



MyClass.methods.get(function() {
   console.info(this.name) // => returns undenfined
}.bind(MyClass));
```

I mean only the function call get with **.bind(MyClass)**

Comment: My answer doesn't use any globals.

Comment: Ferdinand's answer is the same as mine, but with a different variable name